# Deploy & consume static content for use with a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, windows-services

I am trying to create a Windows Service that pulls data from a Linq-to-SQL data access layer.  For the DAL, I'm using external XML mapping files.

Things seem to build fine, but after I install the service and try to start it I get the following error:

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could
>   not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Windows\system32\Generated\SpiSytelineMapping.xml'.

First of all, I'm trying to figure out why it's looking for the mapping file in the system32 directory rather than the directory where the service executable is located.

Even so, when I browsed to the system32 directory I was surprised to see that the content files were indeed copied there.

> ```
> C:\Windows\System32\Generated>dir
>
>  Directory of C:\Windows\System32\Generated
>
> 08/24/2011  02:32 PM    <DIR>          .
> 08/24/2011  02:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
> 08/24/2011  02:09 PM           447,079 AbcSytelineMapping.xml
> 08/24/2011  02:09 PM           442,374 HtiSytelineMapping.xml
> 01/19/2011  05:07 PM           445,155 MpiCorpSytelineMapping.xml
> 08/24/2011  02:09 PM           464,353 SpiSytelineMapping.xml
> 08/24/2011  02:09 PM           440,483 SytelineMapping.xml
>                5 File(s)      2,239,444 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  56,826,531,840 bytes free
> ```

Since the files are there, my first assumption was that this is a permissions issue, but the directory and the files have read permissions for 'Everyone', and I tried starting the service under 'Administrator', 'Local Service', 'Local System', and my account (which is also an admin account.  All failed with the same error.

It is worth noting that the files also appear in the application's install directory with the executable.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a windows service start, it started in c:\windows\system32, maybe you can do this when load your mappings:

```
string connStr = "server=.;database=AdventureWorksLT;integrated security=true;";
string currentPath=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
using (CustomDataContext context = new CustomDataContext(connStr, XmlMappingSource.FromUrl(currentPath+"\\CustomerMapping.xml")))
{

}
```

To force to load the xml from the current directory where is located the windows service.

Comment: This works, and I think it will be cleaner in my other applications that also use this Linq-to-SQL class library as well.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

While the above works, I found it much better to embed the mapping file as a resource and load it from there with the following:

```
    private static string GetXmlMapping()
    {
        Stream xmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Mpicorp.SytelineDataModel.Generated.SytelineMapping.xml");
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(xmlStream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

This is very simple and much more elegant; my data access layer is much easier to deploy now.  I was simply ignorant of this method when I made my original post.  Perhaps this may be useful to someone who has the same dilemma.